# Microphone not working on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, 21.10

I have an integrated laptop microphone, it works well on Windows but ever since I switched to Ubuntu, it doesn't work and pulseaudio volume control shows no sound output from the microphone output. I have tried many solutions - pavucontrol, alsamixer, editing the alsa.conf file etc. but none of them prevail.

But, one of them actually worked - the solution was that all I needed to do was mute my Front Right part of my microphone and only enable sound from the Front Left part. And yes! It worked and my microphone was now able to produce output. But, whenever I check my mic in my browser or use Microsoft Teams (online classes), the Front Right part of the microphone (which was muted) automatically unmutes itself and equates both the Front Right and Front Left, and that cuts off my voice in between. Even if I change it back, a few seconds later when I start to speak it again equates both the parts. Any help on how I can lock the setting or any other solution would be appreciated.

Information:

OS: Ubuntu 21.10 dual booted w/ Windows 10

Kernel Version: 5.13.0-20-generic

Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

Laptop Model: Lenovo Ideapad 130-15ikb

Screenshots:
[this configuration makes my microphone work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv3JT.png)

[this is what it automatically changes to after a few seconds of me speaking into my mic (as you can see no microphone input is showing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFtQY.png)